# Using Antd's message with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using

"antd": "^4.21.3", "typescript": "^4.7.4" with react 18, and I am facing the problem of error config type! The error message is below..

```
// current code
import { message } from 'antd'

function AlertModal({ type = 'success', duration = 3, ...props }) {
const config = {
    duration: duration,
    ...props,
}
return message[type as keyof typeof message](config)
}
export default AlertModal
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how can I solve this annoying problem??

Comment: I'm looking at both [the implementation](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/message/index.tsx) and the error message, seems that MessageAPI attribute args are getting resolved into a lot of things, and some branch of that is probably getting messed up. Try defining config as ArgsProps (`const config: ArgsProps = ...`). If that doesn't help define `message` as `message[type as keyof Omit<typeof message, 'destroy' | 'useMessage'>]` as those two are probably causing issues.

Comment: @5ar  I used `message[type as keyof Omit<typeof message, 'destroy'>](config)` and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just rewrite what's in the comments with some extra details, so that this question can be treated as answered.

The `message` import references the default export of [this file](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/message/index.tsx) which is typed as [`MessageApi`](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/b3eec68e18ae8be7144fa1ddbd17b3bc766fe419/components/message/index.tsx#L267), and the expression `message[type as keyof typeof message]` is evaluated as follows:

```
(content: JointContent, duration?: ConfigDuration, onClose?: ConfigOnClose) => MessageType
| (args: ArgsProps) => MessageType
| (options: ConfigOptions) => void
| (messageKey?: React.Key) => void
| () => [MessageInstance, React.ReactElement]
```

TypeScript in this scenario regards all of these function typings as equally possible so it tries to cast the `config` object as the first argument as each of those function types.

The problem arises when trying to cast an object to `React.Key` which is defined as `string | number`. `config` (or any object type) is just not a valid argument for that case and TypeScript is doing its job in warning you about that case.

However, in the implementation we can probably assume that certain special message types will not be called, such as the message type `destroy`. `MessageApi['destroy']` is the only `MessageApi` function property that uses the `React.Key` argument, so removing (i.e. omitting) that typing would solve the issue. This can be easily done just by changing the keyof message cast to:

```
return message[type as keyof Omit<typeof message, 'destroy'>](config)
```